# Can I replace the default code editor in Android Studio with VSCode or Atom or Sublime ,etc?

Tags: android, android-studio

What confused me is the code editor in AS which is not as beautiful as VScode or Atom , is there any possible to replace it with others?

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking if Android Studio can run a full text editing program within itself. To that the answer is no.

However, what it sounds like you really want is just the styling of other editors. Android Studio does offer significant customization of the code editor. You can customize fonts, syntax highlighting colors, and much more. You can set these options in the Android Studio settings under **Editor > Colors & Fonts**. See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) for more information.

If you want certain *features* of those other text editing programs, you might find [an IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/?idea) that provides the functionality you are looking for.